# Getting this error while running test.`remove_method': method `run' not defined in ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForMinitest (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am following the michael Hartl tutorial and ran into a small problem.Everything was going fine uptill I added the test for my contact us page.

```
 static_pages_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

 class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 test "should get home" do
get :home
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end 
test "should get help" do
 get :help
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end

test "should get about" do
get :about
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end

end
```

Here is my gem file

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

 


    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do    
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
      gem 'guard'
     
     end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
      gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
      gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
      gem 'sprockets-rails', '=2.0.0.backport1'
      gem 'sprockets', github: 'tessi/sprockets', branch: '2_2_2_backport2'
  

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

After updating my test file I ran bundle exec rake test and after that I got few errors like.

> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest
> /old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in remove_method': method run' not
> defined in ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForMinitest
> (NameError).

Please let me know if more information is required.

Adding Full stack trace.

```
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest /old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in `remove_method': method `run' not defined in ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForMinitest (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in `<module:ForMinitest>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:6:in `<module:SetupAndTeardown>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:5:in `<module:Testing>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:67:in `use_old_activesupport_fix!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:28:in `use!'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/unit/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/unit/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in `remove_method': method `run' not defined in ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForMinitest (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in `<module:ForMinitest>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:6:in `<module:SetupAndTeardown>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:5:in `<module:Testing>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:67:in `use_old_activesupport_fix!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:28:in `use!'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/functional/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/functional/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in `remove_method': method `run' not defined in ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForMinitest (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:7:in `<module:ForMinitest>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:6:in `<module:SetupAndTeardown>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:5:in `<module:Testing>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/old_activesupport_fix.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:67:in `use_old_activesupport_fix!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.0.5/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:28:in `use!'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/abhishek/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]>
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/**/*_test.rb" ]>
Errors running test:integration! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/integration/**/*_test.rb" ]>
```

test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!


class ActiveSupport::TestCase
# Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in    alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in  integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Comment: Hello There. Can we see the full list of errors you received? That will help us narrow down the cause for this. Thanks!

Comment: I cant add so many lines here.Tough apart from the error I mentioned above this is the second one coming at the end. Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]>
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/**/*_test.rb" ]>

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace there. Adding it in the comments makes it very hard to read and understand.

Comment: choose the ruby and its gemset before executing something in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it has been solved after reinstall current Ruby

```
rvm uninstall 2.5.3
rvm install 2.5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Allrighty- one big error I see is in the test itself:

```
require 'test_helper'
    end *****
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "should get home" do
   get :home
   assert_response :success
   assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
```

So not sure why that first `end` is there right after `require 'test_helper'` (with the extra stars)

Now having a superfluous `end` would ordinarily give us an error that has this included: `SyntaxError: ... syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`, but lets start by removing that `end` then `bundle exec rake test` and let us know the results.

Thanks!

---

EDIT

Looking at your test_helper.rb try changing:

`ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'`

to

`ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`

Comment: removed that "end" and ran bundle exec rake test.Still the issue persists.@tmehta2442

Comment: @holger just : Added the full stack trace.Please let me know if it is fine.

Comment: Great, thanks for adding that. I also see an error with your `integration/site_layout_test.rb` & `/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb`. Can you also attach those files for our review? Thanks!

Comment: I dont have any such files yet.

Comment: Hmmm... are you sure? The `/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb` should have been created when you generated your StaticPages controller. And you are getting an error for the` site_layout_test.rb` so that is in there somewhere (I think!). THe full route is `test/integration/site_layout_test.rb` and `test/helpers/static_pages_helper_test.rb`.

Comment: Oh, can we take a look at your `test_helper too`? The path is `test/test_helper.rb`

Comment: Added my test helper.rb and my static_pages_helper_test.rb is empty.It only has two line of code i.e module StaticPagesHelper
end

Comment: I just edited my answer, essentailly try changing that first line of `test_helper.rb` to: `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`