# Ruby on rails, I can not run rails server command, method `source' not defined in Gem::Specification Window 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently installing ruby on rails on Win10.  when I am runing

```
\blog\bin> rails server
```

it always shows this issue

---

```
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:14:in `<module:Gem>'

         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:17:in `<class:Specification>'

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:17:in `remove_method': method `source' not defined in Gem::Specification (NameError)
```

---

My current environment

```
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]

rails 4.0
```

Do I miss something ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem lies on your `Gemfile`. Check if the file there has a line with `source` on top of it

Comment: Did you check the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807995/getting-this-error-while-running-test-remove-method-method-run-not-defined